# How do I change the "actual encoding" of my HTML document?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I ran my web page through the W3C HTML validator and received this error.

> The encoding ascii is not the preferred name of the character
>   encoding in use.   The preferred name is us-ascii. (Charmod C024) ✉ 
>   Line 5, Column 70: Internal encoding declaration utf-8 disagrees with
>   the actual encoding of the document (us-ascii).

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

Apparently, I am not "actually" using UTF-8 even though I specified UTF-8 in my meta tag.

How do I, well, "actually" use UTF-8? What does that even mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The HTML5 mode of the validator treats a mismatch between encoding declarations as an error. In the message, “internal encoding declaration” refers to a `meta` tag such as `<meta charset=utf-8>`, and “actual encoding” (misleadingly) refers to encoding declaration in HTTP headers.

According to current HTML specifications (HTML5 is just a draft), the mismatch is not an error, and the HTTP headers win.

There is no real problem if your document only contains Ascii characters. Ascii-encoded data is trivially UTF-8 encoded too, because in UTF-8, any Ascii character is represented as a single byte, with the same value as in Ascii.

It depends on the software used server-side whether and how you can change the HTTP headers. If they now specify charset=ascii, as it seems, it is not a real problem except in validation, provided that you keep using Ascii characters only. But it is somewhat odd and outdated. Try to have the encoding information there changed to charset=utf-8. You need not change the actual encoding, but if you later add non-Ascii characters, make sure you save the file as UTF-8 encoded by selecting a suitable command or option in the authoring program.

Answer (score 3):

Open your file in notepad, then `save as` > `UTF-8` (next to the `save` button).

Answer (score 2):

On unix-like system you might use `iconv` tool to convert file from one encoding to another.
It can also be used from the scope of programming language(e.g. php).
The proper function has same name:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php

Answer (score 1):

Specifying encoding is one thing. Saving documents in a proper encoding is another.
Edit your documents in editors supporting [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoding. Preferably UTF-8 without BOM. [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) may be a good start.
Have a read too: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).