# encoding warnings and error by validator of a simple static html page

Tags: html, css, character-encoding

I am new to HTML and CSS and just practice my home page.

http://www.utdallas.edu/~siming.liu/

If I check it by validator, it will show following error messages.

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.utdallas.edu%2F~siming.liu%2F

```
Warning: Using windows-1252 instead of the declared encoding iso-8859-1.

Warning: Legacy encoding windows-1252 used. Documents should use UTF-8.

Error: Internal encoding declaration utf-8 disagrees with the actual encoding of the document (windows-1252).
```

I've checked my raw html and CSS files' encoding and line ending, they are pure ASCII.

So they should be also UTF-8.

So what's wrong in the page?

Answer (score 0):

There are two places I found that you should check out.

The [first](https://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) is in regards to checking if your site is properly in UTF-8. And it will basically see if it could handle international characters etc, basically things that UTF-8 could handle but something like ISO-8859-1 could not.

The other is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158743/how-do-i-change-the-actual-encoding-of-my-html-document) that talks about a known issue with HTML5 and thinking there is errors with the UTF-8 or legacy encoding. You may just have an error message but no real issue.